# Connect PGAdmin3 to OpenShift PostgreSQL Database

Tags: postgresql, ssh, openshift, portforwarding, pgadmin

I am attempting to build and run a simple Java Tomcat web app on OpenShift that connects to a PostgreSQL database. I want to use PGAdmin3 to access the remote database.
I can access the database with **psql** on my local machine using port-forwarding:

```
./psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5434 testdb -Uadmin6synqbm
```

I am happy that my identity file, private key and pass phrase are good as they work in other situations.

I have set up a Server called **OpenShif**t on **PGAdmin3** and tried to connect to the database using **SSH Tunneling** but I just get the following error message:

**SSH error: Authentication by identity file failed with error code - 16**

My set up follows...
**On OpenShift:-**

```
PostgreSQL 9.2  Database: testdb User: admin6synqbm Password: ????
ssh 579792ef0c1e66011b00017b@testdb-infomediauk.rhcloud.com
```

**On PGAdmin:-**

**Has anyone managed to do this successfully? Any help would be much appreciated.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST=127.9.247.2
    OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PASSWORD=????
    OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT=5432
    OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_USERNAME=admin6synqbm
    OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL=postgresql://admin6synqbm:????@127.9.247.2:5432

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd let you all know, this setup does work. I rebooted my workstation and restarted my OpenShift application, then retried to connect and it worked.

I got a dialog with the following information on it:-

```
**Host key received for the SSH server "testdbinfomediauk.rhcloud.com" is
B9 65 49 1B D7 D5 D1 22 4E 2A 90 C4 0A C2 55 C4 CA A9 CC 7D
Would you like to accept it and continue with the connection?**
```

I clicked OK and it worked!